# Como editar/agregar código a botón en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

estoy buscando el modo de llegar al código de un botón de Wordpress.
La idea es cambiar o agregar funcionalidad, por ejemplo, si el usuario ya está loggeado no debería aparecer. (Incluso este código ya lo tengo)
Lo que necesito saber, es donde, en carpeta/archivo está dicho botón.
Lo he estado buscando sin poder llegar a él.

Dicho botón se encuentra en un menú desplegable, que está contenido en el header: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/3b8e2a9e53d79047b2f65c6de620c805.png) 
Al mostrar los datos, logro obtener que input es: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/fbbf759e82afa0027d831e75038893dd.png) 
Pero si busco ese input directamente dentro del proyecto, no encuentro nada: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/e928c1daeb038ffd42c85a2d98888e6a.png)
Y desde wordpress, solo obtengo esto: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/9a72686fcfa8bee218942f140cf1e496.png)

Comment: Que tema estas usando??

Comment: Customify es el tema

Comment: el botón estaba en Menu Sidebar, lo quite desde wordpress, pero no encuentro su codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código del botón lo puedes encontrar en los archivos de tu tema, específicamente en la carpeta inc/customizer/configs/header/button.php específicamente en la línea 68, se agrega al fronted del tema con el siguiente codigo:

```
echo '<a' . $target . ' href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( join( ' ', $classes ) ) . '">';
        if ( 'after' != $icon_position ) {
            echo $icon_html . esc_html( $text );
        } else {
            echo esc_html( $text ) . $icon_html;
        }
        echo '</a>';
```

Para ocultar dicho botón para usuarios logueados puedes usar la función is_user_logged_in() de wordpress, englobando el código que se encarga de hacer echo del botón, de esta forma:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        } else {

            echo '<a' . $target . ' href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( join( ' ', $classes ) ) . '">';
            if ( 'after' != $icon_position ) {
                echo $icon_html . esc_html( $text );
            } else {
                echo esc_html( $text ) . $icon_html;
            }
            echo '</a>';

        }
```

Siempre recuerda de hacer cambios al código fuente de tu tema desde un child-theme para no perder esos cambios al momento de actualizar el tema

Comment: Dentro de la funcion render() si no estoy mal. Gracias :3 Ahora, a que te refieres con hacer ese cambio al child ?

Comment: No se si estas editando directamente el tema, si es asi prueba a crear un child-theme o tema hijo para evitar problemas al momento de actualizar, si ya lo estas usando entonces no te preocupes por eso, por cierto, si mi respuesta te ayudo agradecería que la marques como aceptada

Comment: No se a que te refieres con child theme, pero lo buscare. Y si, es lo que buscaba